# Как получить видимые на карте объекты?

Tags: leafletjs

Вот например событие zoomend сработало, как получить те объекты которые видны сейчас на карте?

```
map.on('zoomend', function(ee) {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какие объекты вы хотите получать? Если, например, у вас есть ассоциативный массив маркеров `marks`, то получить из них видимые можно следующим образом:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(ee) {  
  var bounds = map.getBounds(); // границы видимой области карты 
  for (var key in marks) { // обходим массив маркеров 
    if (marks.hasOwnProperty(key) &&  
      /^0$|^[1-9]\d*$/.test(key) &&  
      key <= 4294967294) {  
      var lat_lng = marks[key].getLatLng(); // координаты маркера
      if (bounds.contains(lat_lng)) { // проверяем, попадает ли маркер в границы области
        console.log(lat_lng);
      }
    }
  }
});
```